# Check if string equals value dict, with correction for whitespaces instead of '-'

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

**Set-up**

I am scraping housing ads and obtain a subdistrict per ad. I also have a dictionary containing districts (keys) and subdistricts (values).

A part of the dictionary looks like,

```
d = {
      'Antony':['Antony','Châtenay-Malabry','Sceaux','Bourg-la-Reine','Bagneux',
               'Fontenay-aux-Roses','Le Plessis-Robinson','Clamart',
               'Châtillon','Montrouge','Malakoff','Vanves']
         ⋮
    }
```

---

**Problem**

I assign a district name to each ad by using its subdistrict and the above dictionary:

```
for distr, subdr in d.items():
     if subdistrict in subdr:
          district = distr
          break
     else:
          district = 'unknown'
```

However, for some ads I obtain a subdistrict with whitespaces in stead of `'-'` in the name, e.g. `'Fontenay aux Roses'` instead of `'Fontenay-aux-Roses'`. Moreover, I cannot rule out that all `'-'` are replaced – i.e. `'Fontenay aux-Roses'` could be retrieved.

How do I tell Python that e.g. `'Fontenay aux-Roses'`, `'Fontenay aux Roses'` or any other possible combination are all `'Fontenay-aux-Roses'`?

My actual dictionary is large and contains multiple district names with this issue.

I can think of repetitive solutions, but was wondering if there is something more elegant.

Comment: Strip things like '-' and uppercase letters from your reference data and then apply the same process when comparing new values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard `str.replace(old, new[, count])` will work, along with dict comprehension:

```
d = {
      'Antony':['Antony','Châtenay-Malabry','Sceaux','Bourg-la-Reine','Bagneux',
               'Fontenay aux Roses','Le Plessis-Robinson','Clamart',
               'Châtillon','Montrouge','Malakoff','Vanves']
    }

d = {k: [item.replace(' ', '-') for item in v] for k, v in d.items()}
```